# Error with empty request on group by desc in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

If write this SQL request without data inside I have an error in my PHP server.

It comes from this line group by `dateday desc`. If I remove `desc` it works well. If I populate the data and I use this request below, it works well.

Do you have an idea to resolve this problem?

```sql
select date_format(o.date_purchased, "%M") as dateday, sum(ot.value) as total
from mys_orders o, mys_orders_total ot
where date_sub(now(), interval 12 month) <= o.date_purchased
and o.orders_status = 3
and o.orders_id = ot.orders_id
and (ot.class = 'ST')
group by dateday desc
```

Comment: `group by dateday desc` you probably mean `order by dateday desc`? Then `group by date_format(o.date_purchased, "%M")` (the order is then group by => order by)?

Comment: You probably want: `group by dateday order by dateday desc`

Comment: @juergend Since `dateday` is an alias of `date_format(o.date_purchased, "%M")`, and not an actual column, it can't be inside a `GROUP BY` clause. Only in `ORDER BY` can one use aliased values.

Comment: @Qirel: Wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e9b7/2

Comment: If you look at the select statement in the manual you will see that GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...  no longer exists in version 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html it does in 5.7 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: @P.Salmon: Still works in 8+: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4uixanPXHrW11owy2PLar/0

Comment: @jurgen your link has a group by and an order by - thats not the same as group by desc..

Comment: @P.Salmon: Now I know what you mean. But still works anyway: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4uixanPXHrW11owy2PLar/1

Comment: @jurgen maybe  'Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, MySQL supported a nonstandard syntax extension that permitted explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html I wonder what version OP is on.

Comment: What version are you on (show variables like 'version')